# $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y), \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$. If $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f=L$, prove that $L=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y), \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$

I can see that $f(2x)=f(x)+f(x)=2f(x)$ and $f(x-c)=f(x)-f(c)$, also that $f(0)=0$.

**Nothing is mentioned about continuity of the function, so I cannot use the assumption of continuity.**

To prove that $L=0$, I need to show that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ when $|x-c|<\delta$

I don't know how to go about it. Please help!

Comment: Hint: $2L=\lim_{x\to0}2f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(2x)=L$.

Comment: You can use the continuity of $f$. You can check that if $f$ is continuous at a point then $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @sranthrop Beautiful. Deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @sranthrop I used that and got the proof done. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $2L=\lim_{x\to0}2f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(2x)=L$, so $L=0$.

Answer (score 2):

By induction show that $f(nx)=nf(x)$, hence $f(\tfrac1n)=\frac1nf(1)\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** if $f$ is identically $0$, you are done. Suppose it is not, i.e. there exists $x^\ast$ such that $f(x^\ast)\neq 0$.

You can show that $f(x^\ast) = 2^n f\!\left(\frac{x^\ast}{2^n}\right) $ for all $n \geq 0$ (by induction). And the assumption $\lim_0 f = L$ implies that $f\!\left(\frac{x^\ast}{2^n}\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} L$ (this is not assuming continuity, only the limit: nothing says $f(0)=L$). Can you conclude?

Comment: This is becoming a bit complicated for me....

Comment: The spacing does not help -- I wrote is as a block. Try to go through each step slowly: they are not, individually, very hard.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard approach to such problems: Assume $L\neq0$. Show, by using the additive property, that given a small enough $\epsilon$ (like $\frac{|L|}{10}$, for instance) there is *no* $\delta$ that works.

Answer (score 1):

[It is easy to show that $f(x) = f(1)x$, whenever $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation)

Now since you are given that $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = L$ exists, we can consider convergence to $0$ along the sequence $x_n=1/n$, i.e., we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(1/n) = L$. This implies that $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(1)}n = 0$.